# What force creates ions out of neutral atoms?

Tags: electromagnetism, physical-chemistry, atomic-physics, ions

Consider the reaction between Na and Cl to form NaCl.

Na loses an electron and "gives" it to Cl because this makes both atoms more stable.

But what forces "pulls" the electron from Na to Cl? Both atoms are electrically neutral at the beginning, so the electron that is going to be transferred isn't acted on by electrostatic forces.

Since its not electrostatic forces that pull the electron from Na to Cl (since both atoms are neutral) what force pulls the electron from Na to Cl to make both atoms more stable?

Comment: the forces have the covering name of Van der Waals forces ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force ). They are spill over forces because the electron orbitals ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbitals ) do not cover the whole space uniformly and thus dipole ( see @vinay answer ) quadrupole and higher moments allow electric fields, attractive and/or repulsive to manifest in the space around the atom/molecule. These create the chemical attractions and repulsions. BTW it is the molecule that is the stable configuration, the combination and not the individual atoms.

Comment: i.e. the quantum mechanical solution of the molecule has a lower energy level than if the individual atoms were independent.

Comment: Another point to consider is that reactions like this rarely occur in the elemental form: $Na + Cl \rightarrow NaCl$. It's usually an acid-base neutralization, which is basically a reaction of $Na^+$ and $Cl^-$.

Comment: Your point is still valid, though: what force *causes* the electron to move from Na to Cl? Other things to consider are: 1) When you talk about a chemical reaction, it's usually at very very small-scale distances. There's not really much movement of the electron. 2) Electron isn't really a negative ball. It's also a wave, which complicates stuff further.

Comment: As long as the energy is reduced, you can derive an attractive force based on the Hellmann-Feynman theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation that if we have simply an $Na$ atom and a $Cl$ atom they would exchange electrons and make $NaCl$, is wrong !

To make the necessary electron exchange they need to get very very close, so close that their electronic orbitals (place where electrons reside) overlap in after coming into this region 2 things can happen

1. The electron that is to be shared hangs somewhere in the middle of both atoms; This is known as a covalent bond usually formed between atoms of similar electronegativities.
2. The electron that is to be shared shifts too much towards one atom; This is known as ionic bond usually formed between atoms of different electronegativities.

Now collisions between atoms are constantly made, sometimes the atoms repel due to different orientation of their **induced** dipoles and sometimes attract, even when their orientation is right they come so close only when they have sufficient energy known as **activation energy**.

Another point of discussion is that when electrons are in such a close vicinity what causes the exchange from one atom to another.

In short, **Z-effective** this is the net charge of the neucleus felt by the electrons at different locations of the atom. Z-effective of a more electronegative is more even on the outer section of atom and hence an electron feels more attracted towards a more electronegative atom. This is what happens in case of $NaCl$, when the atoms come too close the electron migrates from $Na$ to $Cl$ due to the difference in electronegativities of the atoms.

Comment: How the hell do you know so much? I'm the same age as you and you've been answering all my questions! :)

Comment: Where do you live ? What are you studying ?

Comment: Cananda, Electrical Engineering at U of T.

Comment: I am in India, preparing for udergraduate entrance exams for engineering; but I hasten to ask you not to credit our system for my knowing a bit more than I am supposed to. This particular question however is of our course only and many students know it as subjects such as chemistry, physics, maths are cumpolsory to science stream students here. But to tell the truth I study less of course and more of popular science and what not :) BTW you havent accepted any of my answers !

Answer (score 0):

It isn't correct to think of the electron as a little ball that is plucked from the sodium atom and thrown into the chlorine atom. The electrons in atoms don't have a defined position. Instead the electrons occupy a region of space centred on the atom, with the probability of finding the electron decreasing with distance but in principle extending to infinity.

So if you have a sodium atom and a chlorine atom in close proximity (but still farther away than the NaCl bond length) there is a small but non-zero probability of finding the $3s$ sodium electron within the chlorine atom. You don't have to move the electron to the chlorine atom because there is a finite probability that is already there!

If you could watch as the two atoms were brought together you'd see their electron *atmospheres* start to overlap, and as they did so the interaction between them would increase the electron density near the chlorine atom and decrease it near the sodium atom. However all that is changing is the probability of finding the various electrons, and this increases gradually. There is no sudden transition where an electron pops off the sodium atom and onto the chlorine atom.

Comment: I am not saying that this is at all wrong, but while schroding equations give non zero probability density of electron of sodium being found near chlorine, it also gives extremely small but non zero density of finding that electron near **mars**. Also, as you correctly say that one just have to shift probability density a little towards other atom, it does involvd actual shifting of electrons if seen from particle nature.

Comment: Pardon me if am wrong. I have a question here, isn't orbital overlapping concept is explained for covalent bonds (where we have hybridzation)?. But here $NaCl$ is ionic bond.

Comment: @VINAY: my point was that the orbitals overlap as the two atoms approach each other. However note that there is no clear distinction between a covalent and ionic bond. Even in an ionic bond the highest occupied molecular orbital covers both atoms, though it's true that the probability of finding the electron on the sodium atom is low compared to the chlorine atom.

Comment: @VINAY : maybe [Fajan's rule](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fajans'_rules) can help you here, it clearly states that both ionic and covalent bonds have features of one another, it depends on the polarisationg of bonds which in turn depends on where the electron density is more as said by john.

Answer (score -1):

The stronger positive nucleus of one atom firstly pulls the electron(s) of the other atom. This makes one atom positively charged and one negatively charged causing an ionic bond to be formed